# Hide / Show multiple div by classes name

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

http://maximebichon.net/test.html

Here is the website.
My problem is very simple.
As you can see on the page, at the bottom of the menu it says "fr / en". Obviously, I would like to have some kind of french / english switch.
Since it's a handcoded website, I tought that I could add some simple jquery which, which when the user click on fr or en, it hides a specific class and shows another one.

Here is the code I have used so far (found on stackoverflow) :

```
$(document).click(function() {
var toggleElements = $(".toggleMe");
$.each(toggleElements, function (key, value) {
   if (value.hasClass('hidden')) {
       value.removeClass('hidden');
       value.addClass('shown');
   } else {
       if (value.hasClass('shown')) {
           value.removeClass('shown');
           value.addClass('hidden');
       }
   }
});
});
```

Here is the css (pretty simple)

```
.hidden{
display: none;
}
.shown{
display: block;
}
```

Could you tell me what's wrong? 
And what should I add to link's href or class in order to switch the language ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the jQuery `.toggleClass()` method like:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    var $toggleElements = $(".toggleMe");
    $toggleElements.toggleClass('hidden shown');
});
```

[**DEMO #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/aFbFA/)

Comment: Can you be more precise ? I am ok with css/html but jquery is not my something I am very good at. 
What should I add to the link attributes? 
How can I affect the specific div according to their classes?

Comment: Have a look at the demo please. That might help you to understand it. In case, you have any more query, let me know.

Comment: thanks for the help, we are getting closer!
well, it does switch, which is nice. But every link now make the switch happen. (--> http://maximebichon.net/test.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your logic is correct, try using $(value) instead of 'value'

```
$(document).click(function() {
var toggleElements = $(".toggleMe");
$.each(toggleElements, function (key, value) {
   if ($(value).hasClass('hidden')) {
       $(value).removeClass('hidden');
       $(value).addClass('shown');
   } else {
       if ($(value).hasClass('shown')) {
           $(value).removeClass('shown');
           $(value).addClass('hidden');
       }
   }
});
});
```

Comment: Same questions than above...
Where should I put the toggleMe in my html?
How can it affect specific classes?

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
var $toggleElements = $(".toggleMe");  
$toggleElements.click(function () {
    $toggleElements.toggleClass('hidden shown');
});
```